# How to resolve Key in dictionary: '1' Key being added:'1' error?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powercli

I am trying to add a new key(1) to a hashtable, but powershell throws the error as "Key in dictionary: '1'  Key being added:'1' error", same issue comes when I add 2 as a key but no issues with key '3' in a hashtable.

Here is my code to which does adding key to a hashtable.

```bsh
$esxarray = @('10.91.91.XX8', '10.91.91.XX9')

foreach ($i in $esxarray) {
    Connect-VIServer -Server $i
}


$podnumbers = @(1, 3)
    
$podInfo = $null
$PodHASHTABLE = @{}
$buffer = 0
foreach ($pd in $podnumbers) {
    $podinfo = @()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pd; $i = $i + 1) {
        $pod = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for", $esxarray[$buffer]
        Write-Output `n
        $podinfo += $pod
    }
    $podSet = @{ $pd = @($podinfo) }
    $podInfObj = New-Object psobject –Property $podSet
    $PodHASHTABLE += $podSet
    $buffer = $buffer + 1
}
```

Here is the error I got after executing the script.

```
Item has already been added.  Key in dictionary: '1' Key being added: '1'
+ $PodHASHTABLE += $podSet
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, even if I enter `1` in all 4 prompts, it works as expected. Perhaps you typo'd `$pod` as `$pd`?

Comment: i have corrected the typo but still the error persists

Comment: So after fixing the typo, if you open a new powershell process and run the code, you're still getting that same error?

Comment: yes, the same error and below changes is what I've done
 $pod = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for",$esxarray[$buff]
    $podinfo += $pod
    }
$podSet = @{$pd= $podinfo}

Comment: Fascinating. No idea. What version of PowerShell does this occur in?

Comment: PS version is 5.1.1